# Using the Azure Management Fluent Apis. I would like like to deploy an azure function including the zipped code. Is that possible?

Tags: deployment, azure-functions

I know how to create the app service plan . I need to be able to deploy the code and the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create a function app using Azure Management Fluent Api.

You can use the below [ifunctionapp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.ifunctionapp?view=azure-dotnet) interface to create the function app using fluent api's:

```
    public interface IFunctionApp :
Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.IWebAppBase,
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.IBeta,
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.IGroupableResource<Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.IAppServiceManager,Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.Models.SiteInner>,
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.IHasInner<Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.Models.SiteInner>,
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.IHasManager<Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.IAppServiceManager>,
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.ResourceActions.IRefreshable<Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.IFunctionApp>,
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.ResourceActions.IUpdatable<Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.FunctionApp.Update.IUpdate>
```

using the "[IWithPackageUri.WithPackageUri(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.webdeployment.definition.iwithpackageuri.withpackageuri?view=azure-dotnet)" by specifing the zipped packed to deploy

```
public Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent.WebDeployment.Definition.IWithExecute WithPackageUri (string packageUri);
```